# Getting Rails and mod_passenger to work under Debian with packages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debian, passenger

I am running a Debian squeeze server with these (backported) packages installed:

```
rails          2.3.5-1~bpo50+1
rails-ruby1.8  2.3.5-1~bpo50+1
rake           0.8.7-1~bpo50+1
libapache2-mod-passenger  2.2.11debian-1~bpo50+1
```

I have a Rails application I am trying to run in this environment, but when I load the page I get this error message:

> Actual load error: Could not find
>   RubyGem rails (= 2.3.5) Missing the
>   Rails 2.3.5 gem. Please `gem install
>   -v=2.3.5 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in
>   config/environment.rb for the Rails
>   version you do have installed, or
>   comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use
>   the latest version installed.

There is a constraint that I must use these "official" Rails and mod_passenger Debian packages, so installing Rails and mod_passenger the traditional way via gems is not a possibility.

Comment: Doctor, I'm feeling really ill, can you help me? There is a constraint that I can't take any medicine.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this question on server fault since this isn't really programming.

Comment: If it makes more sense for this to be asked on serverfault, maybe someone could move my question for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
ln -s /usr/share/rails-ruby1.8/ /usr/share/myrailsproject/vendor/rails
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real reason that you should have to use offical gems from debian. You get faster security updates by using rubygems or going for fullblown rvm.

However I would suggest commenting out the RAILS_GEM_VERSION in config/environment.rb and then it should use the version you have installed.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. Now it says "Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0)".